# react native load app only if user is logged in calling AppRegistry.registerComponent multiple times

Tags: android, ios, facebook, react-native

i have a user protected app, i want to authenticate user **before** loading the main app. so i was wondering is it possible to register more than one app and switch between them in runtime ?

for example i can have 3 apps 1. for login, 2. for admins, 3. for users

i register the three, and then run one of them based on condition,

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('LoginApp',()=><LoginApp />);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AdminApp',()=><AdminApp />);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('UserApp',()=><UserApp />);
```

i can see on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html doc page many functions that seem useful, yet there is no documentation on how to use any of these functions :(

runApplication,unmountApplicationComponentAtRootTag seem like they can do what i want but how to implement this ?

Answer (score 2):

You could something like this:

**Register new component:**

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(routeName, component);
```

---

**Unmount the component by tag:**

```
AppRegistry.unmountApplicationComponentAtRootTag(AppRegistry.getAppKeys()?.indexOf(routeName));
```

---

The **RootTag** is the index from registered app keys.

---

**Documentation:**

https://reactnative.dev/docs/appregistry.html#registercomponent

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I cannot help you with how `AppRegistry` would handle this, but I think this is not the right approach to what you are trying to achieve. I would recommend instead to have a conditional in a `MainApp.js` that renders the appropriate 'App' based on a certain condition (your state). For example:

```
class MainApp extends Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {type: 'login'}; // Say your login component is the default one
  }
  render() {
    switch(this.state){
         case 'login': return <LoginApp onLoginSuccessful={type => this.setState({type})}/>
         case 'admin': return <AdminApp/>
         case 'user': return <UserApp/>
   }
  }
}
```

Then, your `index.(android|ios).js` becomes simply:

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MainApp',()=>);

You can extend this approach to read the `type` value from AsyncStorage or any other persistent utility so that the type is permanently stored and your users do not need to log in again, but I think the example covers the basics.